# Meta SO Link-only Discussion Parser: Parse Meta Stack Overflow for Discussions About Link-only Answers

Tags: app, python

The inspiration for this project arose from my observations and personal challenges with the Stack Overflow moderation system, particularly when my "Not An Answer" flags for link-only answers were declined, revealing an ambiguity in the application of Stack Overflow's guidelines. This experience sparked a curiosity about the broader community's encounters with similar issues, as reflected in discussions and questions on Meta Stack Overflow. It led to the desire to systematically explore these concerns, motivating the creation of a project that leverages the Stack Exchange API to automate the analysis of "link only" content discussions and guidelines interpretations.

The project is designed to automate the retrieval and processing of "link only" questions from Meta Stack Overflow and download the referenced answer from Stack Overflow by interacting with the Stack Exchange API. It incorporates functionalities initially spread across three separate scripts into a single, structured Python script. This overview reflects how the project components align with the functionalities of the initially described scripts.

#### Overview of the Project (`meta_so_parser.py`)

- **Class Structure**: The project is organized within a class, `MetaSOParser`, which organizes the functionalities related to fetching, parsing, and downloading "link only" content.
- **Configuration and Logging**:

  - Logging is set up to track operations related to "link only" content.
  - API configuration is loaded from an `ini` file, mirroring the initial setup and loading process described.
- **Fetching and Downloading Content**:

  - The `meta_so_link_only` method matches the functionalities of `metaso_linkonly.py`, fetching questions with "link only" phrases from Meta Stack Overflow, handling pagination, backoff from the API, and saving questions to a JSON file.
  - The `parse_questions_json` method extracts data from the `questions.json` file, similar to `parse_questions_json.py`. It writes question titles, URLs, question bodies, and answers to separate files, utilizing regular expressions to extract URLs.
  - The `download_flagged_link_only_answers` method performs operations akin to `download_flagged_linkonly_answers.py`, extracting answer IDs from URLs, fetching details from the Stack Exchange API, and saving answers to a JSON file.
- **Implementation Details**:

  - Utilizes the Stack Exchange API for data fetching, with error handling and backoff strategies implemented.
  - Regular expressions are employed to extract URLs from question bodies, emphasizing the focus on "link only" content analysis.
  - Python's file handling and JSON manipulation capabilities are leveraged to store and process data.
  - Pagination handling ensures comprehensive data retrieval during the fetching process.
- **Execution Flow**:

  - The script's main execution flow illustrates the sequence of operations: fetching "link only" questions from Meta Stack Overflow, parsing the downloaded JSON to extract and save relevant data, and downloading details of answers flagged as "link only".

This approach efficiently combines data retrieval, processing, and storage functionalities into a unified script, making the project easier to manage, execute, and scale. It focuses on "link only" content analysis on Stack Exchange platforms.

[Stack Overflow Tools on GitHub](https://github.com/trenton3983/stack_overflow/tree/master/Tools)

```python
import requests
import json
import configparser
import time
import logging
import re
from pathlib import Path

# Define a class for parsing Meta StackOverflow
class MetaSOParser:
    # Define constants for the class
    PAGE_SIZE = 100
    LOG_LEVEL = logging.INFO
    TAGS = "discussion"

    # Initialize the parser
    def __init__(self):
        # Set up paths and configuration
        self.current_dir = Path(__file__).parent
        self.config_file_path = self.current_dir / ".." / ".." / "config_api.ini"
        self.config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        self.config.read(self.config_file_path)
        self.api_key = self.config.get("stackapps", "key")
        self.answers = []
        self.links = []
        # Set up logging
        logging.basicConfig(filename=f"./logs/link_only.log", level=self.LOG_LEVEL)

    # Define a method for making API requests
    def api_request(self, url, params):
        # Try to make the request and handle exceptions
        try:
            response = requests.get(url, params=params)
            data = json.loads(response.text)
            if "backoff" in data:
                time.sleep(data["backoff"])
            return data
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            logging.error(f"Request failed: {e}")
            time.sleep(5)
            return None

    # Define a method for getting link-only posts from Meta SO
    def meta_so_link_only(self):
        # Set up the API endpoint and parameters
        questions_url = "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/search/advanced"
        questions = []
        page = 1
        while True:
            params = {
                "order": "desc",
                "sort": "creation",
                "tagged": self.TAGS,
                "site": "meta.stackoverflow.com",
                "filter": "!-*jbN-o8P3E5",
                "key": self.api_key,
                "page": page,
                "pagesize": self.PAGE_SIZE,
                "q": "link only",
            }
            # Make the API request
            data = self.api_request(questions_url, params)
            if not data or not data["items"]:
                break
            # Filter the questions and add them to the list
            questions.extend(
                [
                    question
                    for question in data["items"]
                    if any(
                        x in question["title"].lower()
                        for x in ["link only", "link-only"]
                    )
                ]
            )
            page += 1
        # Write the questions to a file
        with open("output/questions.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(questions, f)
        print(f"Number of questions: {len(questions)}")

    # Define a method for parsing the questions JSON
    @staticmethod
    def parse_questions_json():
        # Open the questions file and read the data
        with open("output/questions.json", "r") as f:
            data = json.load(f)
        # Open output files for writing
        with open(
            "output/question_titles.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8"
        ) as titles_file, open(
            "output/question_urls.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8"
        ) as urls_file, open(
            "output/question_body.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8"
        ) as body_file, open(
            "output/answers.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8"
        ) as answers_file:
            # Loop through the questions and write data to the files
            for question in data:
                titles_file.write(question.get("title", "") + "\n")
                urls = re.findall(
                    r"https?://stackoverflow.com/a/\d+", question.get("body", "")
                )
                for url in urls:
                    urls_file.write(url + "\n")
                body_file.write(question.get("body", "") + "\n")
                for answer in question.get("answers", []):
                    answers_file.write(
                        f"Score: {answer.get('score', '')} - {answer.get('body', '')}\n"
                    )

    # Define a method for downloading flagged link-only answers
    def download_flagged_link_only_answers(self):
        # Open the URLs file and read the data
        with open("output/question_urls.txt", "r") as f:
            urls = f.readlines()
        # Extract the answer IDs from the URLs
        answer_ids = [url.strip().split("/")[-1] for url in urls]
        # Set up the API endpoint
        answers_url = "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/answers/{ids}"
        # Loop through the answer IDs and make API requests
        for answer_id in answer_ids:
            params = {
                "order": "desc",
                "sort": "activity",
                "site": "stackoverflow",
                "key": self.api_key,
                "filter": "!-*jbN-o8P3E5",
            }
            # Set up a dictionary for the answer details
            answer_details = {
                "answer_id": int(answer_id),
                "is_deleted": True,
                "body": "",
                "link": f"https://stackoverflow.com/a/{answer_id}",
            }
            # Make the API request
            data = self.api_request(answers_url.format(ids=answer_id), params)
            if data and "items" in data and data["items"]:
                answer = data["items"][0]
                answer_details["is_deleted"] = answer.get("is_deleted", False)
                answer_details["body"] = answer.get("body", "")
            # Add the answer details to the list
            self.answers.append(answer_details)
        # Write the answers to a file
        with open("output/flagged_link_only_answers.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(self.answers, f)


# Main execution
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create a parser and run the methods
    parser = MetaSOParser()
    parser.meta_so_link_only()
    parser.parse_questions_json()
    parser.download_flagged_link_only_answers()
```